# Use OSM Routing on a Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

Is it possible to use OpenStreetMap data (for routing) on a Google map layer ?

I'm asking this because the Google Directions API is quite expensive, but at the same time I find OSM maps very ugly.

So is it possible to "mix" both the Google map and the OSM data ?? Or if someone knows an OSM map that looks like the Google one, please tell me, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

PS : I am developping on Android

Comment: "I find OSM maps very ugly" -> there are lots of different tile servers available (read: lots of different map styles). And even better: you can create your own one!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I looked at the different tile servers, but every time the maps I find nice aren't free to use (HERE maps, MapBox). I have found a good [open route service](http://openrouteservice.org/) which seems to work very well so I think I will use it with the Google map.

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, what is the price for Google Directions API? I haven't found any infromation on that. Could you provide any information (up-to-date)? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSM license doesn't forbid it: You can do it, as long as you don't mix two datasource for one type of data, so you're good.

You might try e.g. Mapbox, which have some rather nicely looking OpenStreetMap tiles and are also providing directions. They also have an SDK for Android: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at MapBox and it seems pretty good, but now that I have found a good [open route service](http://openrouteservice.org/), I will stick to my first idea and use this service with the Google map

Comment: @DavidSeroussi I would suggest using Graphhopper or OSRM instead, as they are more powerful and also faster in my opinion. They're both OSM based and open source.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why Graphhopper is not free while it uses OSRM which is a free one ?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi Graphhopper does not use OSRM, but it is open source software. They have to pay their bills for development and operation, so if you use their hosted service, you'll need to pay. Open Route Service doesn't give you any guarantees about availability.

Comment: Alright, one last question : if I want to use Graphhopper or ORSM for free, I have to use my own server ?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi yes, you will. (btw, would be nice if you accepted my answer)